# Algebraic + purely transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be an extension of fields of transcendence degree at least $1$. Does there always exist a subfield $K \subset M \subset L$ such that $M/K$ is algebraic and $L/M$ is purely transcendental? If this is not true in general, can some extra conditions on $K$ and $L$ make this work - for example the condition that $L/K$ is finitely generated?

Comment: THere has to be soemthing more here, right? I mean, if $L/K$ is finite then this can never happen for obvious reasons?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5285/4396

Comment: Suppose that $K$ is the algebraic numbers in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $L$ be the algebraic closure of $K(\pi)$.  Then $L/K$ has transcendence degree $1$, but surely no such field $M$ exists.

Comment: What if $K$ is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 3):

Gastón Burrull's comment contains the important idea: if $K$ is algebraically closed, you are asking whether every extension of $K$ is purely transcendental, which is clearly false. For example, when $K = \mathbb{C}$ the fraction field of $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3 - x)$ cannot be purely transcendental because it is the function field of an elliptic curve (which is not birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Comment: Your example is the same as the one given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/why-is-mathbbqt-sqrtt3-t-not-a-purely-transcendental-extension-of-m) and pointed out by wxu's comment above.