# Is $\mathbb{R}(x,\sqrt{1+x^2})$ a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: field-theory, transcendence-degree

I'm working on Exercise 9, Section 19 of Morandi's Field and Galois Theory:

> If $K=\mathbb{R}(x,\sqrt{1+x^2})$, show that there is a $t\in K$ with $K=\mathbb{R}(t)$.

Trying to deduce a workable $t$, I assume if $K=\mathbb{R}(t)$ for some $t$, then I can write $x=g(t)=u(t)/a(t)$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}=f(t)=v(t)/b(t)$ for some rational functions $g$ and $f$ in lowest terms for some polynomials $u,v,a,b$. This gives a relation
$$
f(t)^2=1+x^2=1+g(t)^2
$$
and then
$$
a^2v^2=b^2(a^2+u^2).
$$

Since $v$ and $b$ are coprime, $b^2\mid a^2$, and similarly $a^2\mid b^2$, so $a$ and $b$ are associate in $\mathbb{R}[t]$. Up to scaling $u$ and $v$ a unit, I can assume $a=b$ to put $f$ and $g$ over a common denominator. This leads to an equation
$$
v(t)^2=a(t)^2+u(t)^2
$$
but I'm having a hard time coming up with an appropriate $t$ in terms of $x$ to show $K=\mathbb{R}(t)$. I thought maybe the exercise has a typo, since the book is known to have many errata, and tried disproving it with a method like that found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/why-is-mathbbqt-sqrtt3-t-not-a-purely-transcendental-extension-of-m), but I don't think the same approach works since there isn't a related elliptic curve?

I am wondering if maybe the exercise means to show $\mathbb{R}(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})=\mathbb{R}(t)$ for some $t$? Then for instance $t=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}$ gives
$$
t^2=\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}
$$
which is an invertible linear fractional transformation, so $x\in\mathbb{R}(t^2)\subseteq\mathbb{R}(t)$ and ultimately gives $\mathbb{R}(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})=\mathbb{R}(t)$. I was suspecting this since $x$ and $y:=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ parametrize the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ which seems more standard when considering geometric examples, instead of a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(t)^2 = a(t)^2 + u(t)^2$ can be solved with $a(t) = 2t, u(t) = 1 - t^2, v(t) = 1 + t^2$ (this is essentially the formula for Pythagorean triples) which gives $x = \frac{1 - t^2}{2t}$ and $\sqrt{1 + x^2} = \frac{1 + t^2}{2t}$. Subtracting these gives $t = \boxed{ \sqrt{1 + x^2} - x }$ so this is the desired generator.

A more systematic approach is the following. Write $K$ as the fraction field of $\mathbb{R}[x, y]/(x^2 - y^2 + 1)$ (so $y = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$). Now notice that $x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x - y)$ so making the substitution $u = x + y, v = x - y$ gives that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[u, v]/(uv + 1) \cong \mathbb{R}[u, u^{-1}]$ (or $\mathbb{R}[v, v^{-1}]$) so $K$ is generated by either $u$ or $v$.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the systematic approach in the second half.